# derived table equivalent for sybase 12.0 or how to do updates in batches

Tags: sql, batch-file, updates, sap-ase

I was doing update of big table in Sybase and had following code (declarations skipped):

```
-- get minimum id 
set rowcount 1 
select @min_id = id from table1 where id matches_some_condition

set rowcount 10000 -- batch size

select @max_id = id from 
(select id from table1 where id >= @min_id and some_condition) a order by id

-- do updates
while (1 = 1)
 begin
   update table1
   set a = some_value
   where id >= @min_id and id <= @max_id and further_conditions

   waitfor delay '00:00:01'

   select @min_id = @max_id
   select @max_id = id from 
    (select id from table1 where id >= @min_id and further_conditions
    ) a order by id

   if @min_id >= @max_id
      break

 end
```

So it's usual idea as you can see: take some ordered column (id) and update rows where id is between N and M. Loop until all rows are updated.

As you might see, in order to get @max_id I used `set rowcount 10000` and then `select @max_id = id from (select id from table1 where id >= @min_id and further_conditions) a`. Now I need to do such update on database which is running Sybase ASE 12.0. The problem is that derived tables are only supported from 12.5, so `select id from (select id from table1) a` is not working. Any ideas how to fix it, perhaps algorithm can be changed? Of course, I can do needed updates with the help of cursor, but I was wondering if there was some better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change code:

```
 select @max_id = id from 
    (select id from table1 where id >= @min_id and further_conditions
    ) a order by id
```

to:

```
 select @max_id = max(id) from 
 from table1 
 where id >= @min_id and further_conditions
```

or

```
 select @max_id =  id 
 from table1 
 where id >= @min_id 
 and further_conditions
 order by id
```

Comment: Few hours ago I did exactly that :) Perhaps it was some brain lock when I wrote original code.

Comment: I mean second one, just in case.